# Tinymce does not appear to be working for me

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to get a very basic version of timymce working. I have copied the following from a demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

My tinymce download and my html document are in the same folder, and the src I have given is the correct path from the parent folder.

But all I get is a blank document.

I have tried giving the fill path to the tinymce download, and making changes to the code, but none of it seems to work.

I have searched around for a tutorial to show me the steps needed to get this working but have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested to know, the problem was that I was calling a plugin that I did not have installed :

moxiemanager

The following worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```